# Error while running migration return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params) django.db.utils.OperationalError: near ")": syntax error

Tags: python, django

I am learning Django and making a basic app till now I have coded the account handling part but when I run `python manage.py migrate` I get this is the console I can't understand which file to look into,

```
 Operations to perform:   Apply all migrations: accounts, admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions

Running migrations:   Applying accounts.0003_auto_20180910_1420...Traceback (most recent call last):  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)   File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 303, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params) sqlite3.OperationalError: near ")": syntax error

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception: Operations to perform:   Apply all migrations: accounts, admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions

Running migrations:   Applying accounts.0003_auto_20180910_1420...Traceback (most recent call last):  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)   File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 303, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params) sqlite3.OperationalError: near ")": syntax error

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:   return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)   File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 77, in
_execute_with_wrappers

    return executor(sql, params, many, context)

  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)   File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value   File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 85, in
_execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)   File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 303, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params) django.db.utils.OperationalError: near ")": syntax error
```

As far I remember I have updated my templates and url.py file after the last migration, here is my urls.py.
I can still runserver and I see no errors at the frontend!

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path("signup/", accounts_views.signup, name='signup'),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='login.html'), name='login'),
    path("", views.home, name='home'),
    path('reset/', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(template_name='password_reset.html', email_template_name='password_reset_email.html', subject_template_name='password_reset_subject.txt'), name='password_reset'),
    path('reset/done/', auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(template_name='password_reset_done.html'), name='password_reset_done'),
    path('reset/<int:pk>/', auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(template_name='password_reset_confirm.html'), name='password_reset_confirm'),
    path('reset/complete/', auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(template_name='password_resert_complete.html'), name='password_reset_complete'),
    path('settings/password/', auth_views.PasswordChangeView.as_view(template_name='password_change.html'),
    name='password_change'),
    path('settings/password/done/', auth_views.PasswordChangeDoneView.as_view(template_name='password_change_done.html'),
    name='password_change_done'),
    ]
```

edit 1 :

Here is my migrations file-

```
# Generated by Django 2.0.5 on 2018-09-09 13:41

from django.conf import settings
import django.contrib.auth.models
from django.db import migrations, models
import django.db.models.deletion

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('auth', '0009_alter_user_last_name_max_length'),
        ('accounts', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='User',
            fields=[
                ('user_ptr', models.OneToOneField(auto_created=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, parent_link=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)),
            ],
            options={
                'verbose_name': 'user',
                'verbose_name_plural': 'users',
                'abstract': False,
            },
            bases=('auth.user', models.Model),
            managers=[
                ('objects', django.contrib.auth.models.UserManager()),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.RemoveField(
            model_name='profile',
            name='user',
        ),
        migrations.DeleteModel(
            name='profile',
        ),
    ]
```

second migration file -

```
# Generated by Django 2.0.5 on 2018-09-10 08:50

from django.db import migrations


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('admin', '0002_logentry_remove_auto_add'),
        ('accounts', '0002_auto_20180909_1911'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RemoveField(
            model_name='user',
            name='user_ptr',
        ),
        migrations.DeleteModel(
            name='User',
        ),
    ]
```

Can anyone help me out with this? Where exactly is the syntax error?

Comment: Why have you posted your URLs when the problem is with a migration? You should post that migration.

Comment: Which migration sir? I can't understand which file is causing error.

Comment: Sir, I have 3 migration files which one to post?

Comment: accounts.0003_auto_20180910_1420

Comment: Sir done, can you please have a look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update** - I found the solution problem was with sqllite3 database. I moved to postgresql Everything works fine now!